# Quality Control Heat Map

Tags: quality-control, heatmap

I have data for people about their quality % achieved on a daily basis for last 5 work days, this data is available for one month, say 20 work days.

I have worked out the combinations which is 243. 5 days & 3 Quality ratings (GREEN, RED & YELLOW).

I need to decide on the following:

1. If a person has achieved GREEN consecutively for 5 days I will map him/her as GREEN for the next day, likewise for RED & YELLOW
2. How could I map a person who is getting quality rating as RGYGR or RRGGY or GRYYR for the sixth day? (How could I effectively address the inconsistency here?)

The assigned quality metric is crucial because based on this, # of items to be QC'ed is drawn, say if I mark a person as green, 30% of his/her production goes to QC, for RED 100% goes to QC, for yellow 50% goes to QC.

Also, next day quality map will be produced on last 5 days actual quality% achieved, this will be rolled forward with adding each day actual data, while removing the older data.

Metrics:
0% - 90% RED
90.01% - 94% Yellow
94.01% - 100% - Green

Please let me know if anything is not clear.